# piping a shell function output with trap not working

Tags: bash, pipe, signals, exit

There is a shell function having trap. When the function is called and the output is piped, trap is not working. What is the reason.

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup () {
    echo "====> Calling cleanup"
}

_main () {
    echo "Starting"
    trap 'cleanup' 0
    echo "Completed"
}

 _main | cat
```

If the pipe is removed it works as expected.

```
_main
```

Output with pipe

```
sh -x tp.sh
+ _main
+ echo Starting
+ trap cleanup 0
+ echo Completed
+ cat
Starting
Completed
```

Output WITHOUT pipe

```
$ sh -x tp.sh
+ _main
+ echo Starting
Starting
+ trap cleanup 0
+ echo Completed
Completed
+ cleanup
+ echo '====> Calling cleanup'
====> Calling cleanup
```

Comment: I suggest to set trap before calling function main or replace `0` with `RETURN`.

Comment: This might be the [cause](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html): `Trapped signals that are not being ignored are reset to their original values in a subshell or subshell environment when one is created`.

Comment: @PesaThe I think that applies to traps that exist *before* the subshell is created; here the trap is defined *in* the call to `main`, not *before* the call.

Comment: I see changing `0` to `RETURN` works; I wonder if there is a race condition with the pipe being torn down after `main` completes and the trap firing; the pipe might no longer exist when the handler runs.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus PesaThe and @Chepner for the answers. Changing from EXIT to RETURN works, though I could not understand the reason :)